# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module', but I'm not seeing what's wrong with the path, it seems like it should work

Tags: python-3.x

> 'C:\Users\zPh0eniz\Python lessons'
>
> [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\zPh0eniz\Python lessons\zph0eniz"]
>
> [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\zPh0eniz\Python lessons\my_module"]

I am new at programming but this is what I been trying.

Tested first line by using `sys.path`, shows one of the paths and it seems to check the right place.

Using the file `zph0eniz` to import module from `my_module`

```
import my_module
```

That is when I get the `No module named 'my_module'` error, but it's there...? I am following a tutorial that says if it is in the same folder, it should work. It seems to work for them.

Do I have to add `sys.path` of the exact file of `my_module`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of the space you put between "*Python*" and "*lessons*" in "*Python lessons*" directory

Comment: mm just tried that.  pythonLessons.  Rechecked the path to make sure it got added in too.